# User-specific network settings

Tags: networking, opendns

Is it possible for different user accounts on the same computer to have different network settings?

It seems like most network settings are system-wide (written to `/etc/*`). Is there a way around this?

My goal is to have one user using OpenDNS, while the other users connect without OpenDNS.

That is, for one user, network settings -> IPv4 -> 2 DNS addresses are set and Automatic is off,

whereas for the other users, no DNS address is set and Automatic is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Networking is a system-wide thing, not a per-user thing.